Why deserialize an object to DataContext loss all bindings?
On my Window, I init DataContext this way:
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    private ViewModelData data;
    ResourceManager? resourceManager;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        data = new ViewModelData();
        DataContext = data;
    }
}

And later I add some User Controls passing it to each CTOR:
var uc1 = new MyUserControl(data);
contentGrid.Children.Add(uc1);

var uc2 = new MyUserControl(data);
contentGrid.Children.Add(uc2);

(on each, I've somethings like this):
public MyUserControl(ViewModelData viewModelData)
{
    data = viewModelData;
    DataContext = data;
}

Now, during the live of the app, if on windows I do somethings like:
data.field1 = "value"

it correctly bind the value, and reflect to user control's view.
But once I do somethings like this:
data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ViewModelData>(jsonContent) ?? new ViewModelData();

Taking values from external json, bind seems missing, and Views on each user controls are not updated anymore.
What's wrong? And how can I fix it? Maybe its wrong how can I deal with DataContext (pretty new on WPF).

When you assign a new value to the data member, you would apparently also have to assign a new value to the DataContext property, as you already did with DataContext = data;. It is unclear why you have data at all. In the UserControl constructor, you could as well write DataContext = viewModelData; and a new assignment could be done like DataContext = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject...

if I did DataContext = data;, I still can't see the view on user control update automatically :( I mean, textbox with Binding, don't get the values on json.

You might want to consider creating a separate "Data Transfer objects" (DTOs) to use for serialization. Serializing classes containing logic can be problematic for many reasons. Say your viewmodel contains state that is not meaningful to serialize, or state that is not possible to serialize, like delegates, or asynchronous methods/tasks.

@JonasH can you give a fancy example?

See Create Data Transfer Objects, or one of the many other articles on the subject.

Do not explicitly pass the data value to the UserControls at all. Their DataContext properties will automatically inherit the value of the DataContext property of the MainWindow.
Make no DataContext assignments at all in the UserControls - neither in their XAML nor in their code behind - and create them like this:
var uc1 = new MyUserControl();
contentGrid.Children.Add(uc1);

var uc2 = new MyUserControl();
contentGrid.Children.Add(uc2);

When you later assign a new value to the MainWindow's DataContext, the UserControls will also get this value - automatically by dependency property value inheritance.
DataContext = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ViewModelData>(jsonContent)
            ?? new ViewModelData();


It seems correct, nice! Only a problem: if within a UserControl ctor I init a value of the datamodel, it seems "null" at that time. I mean: within public MyUserControl(), doing var data = DataContext as ViewModelData;, data seems null at that time.

Sure, a property can not be set before construction. You would access the current DataContext in a DataContextChanged event handler.

so I need to add DataContextChanged += MyUserControl_DataContextChanged; on ctor right? which is called once after init?

You can also add an event handler in XAML. The DataContextChanged handler method is called (as the name implies) whenever the DataContext value changes, which according to your question may happen more than once.

I need the event "init" of DataContext, so I can init values only when I start app, not every time DataContextChanged. Is it possible?

Sure, use the Loaded event instead. As a note, you would typically not at all access the DataContext explicitly. It should only provide the implicit source object of the data bindings in your control.

Perfect, clear and useful! Thanks!
